# kafka consumer max-poll-records: 1 - performance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-batch, listener

I have spring boot project with kafka consumer. I need to handle errors if some message arrives - stop the container. So I added those settings:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records: 1
```

Now I need to know what impact (big or not so much) it will have for performance with this setting and without (default 500). If I leave default, then `kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("myID").stop();` does not executes until kafka listener processes all the messages that are in a batch and this is no good for me for order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to measure that. There is script `kafka-verifiable-producer.sh` which can help you produce big amount of messages. And on consumer side you can measure how much it takes to consume all messages with default value and how much with `spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records: 1`

Comment: thanks. is there example for implementation for this script that shows time and takes param max-poll-records?

Comment: Script is already provided. You can download Kafka from here: https://kafka.apache.org/downloads and you will have that script included. You can see here how you can start that script https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/ . You cannot pass max-poll to that script. You can just tell to script to produce million messages to kafka and then set consumer with spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records: 1 and see how long consumer process messages. After you measure that,reconfigure consumer and try again, this time with default settings.

Comment: Why you removed accepted mark from answer? Is there any part of the answer that you don't understand?